# US Immigration Worries - Overstayed in 2000

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, overstaying

I'm a Canadian citizen and back in 2000, when I was young and stupid, I stayed longer than I should have in the US. I entered only with my passport. Eventually I came back to Canada and upon trying to enter back into the US, in 2001, I was denied entry. No stamps were marked in my passport and basically it was just a slap on the wrist. It has been 14 years since then and I haven't set foot in the US since. I'm planning a trip to the US shortly, however, and I would like to know if there is any chance that may cause some kind of problem at Immigration. Any help or information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not contact the US embassy?

Answer (score 3):

Even if they didn't stamp you they may have recorded something on the system.

If you are worried about being denied entry you could get a visa, and explain everything to visa official at the interview. And if you get approved you probably wouldn't have a problem entering the USA.